# KendoUI / Delicious integration issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, kendo-ui, delicious-api

I'm trying to load a Delicious-feed asynchronously using KendoUI, and am running into some weird behavior. My `kendo.dataSource` looks like this (CoffeeScript):

```
deliciousData: new kendo.data.DataSource
  transport:
      read:
        url: 'http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/steven.langbroek?callback=?'
      dataType: 'jsonp'
```

And on my widget I have `<div class="blog-widget-data_delicious" data-source="deliciousData" data-template="deliciousTemplate">`. Now when I load my page I get a console error notifiying me that my domain isn't allowed by access control (the usual when you try to load cross-domain with js). Strange thing is I'm setting my `dataType` to `jsonp`, and I have `?callback=?` in the URL as suggested by pretty much any tutorial I can find on the matter. Even weirder: when I load it through jQuery's `$.getJSON()`, I get the results as expected.

Can anyone help me figure out why this would work with jQuery but not with KendoUI?

Answer (score 0):

Not expert in CoffeeScript but `dataType` is part of `read`, are you not missing a tab? As far as I understand it should be:

```
deliciousData: new kendo.data.DataSource
   transport:
      read:
        url: 'http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/steven.langbroek?callback=?'
        dataType: 'jsonp'
```